# how to remove old jenkins build's console output

Tags: jenkins

in order to not overload Jenkins disk, I would like
to find some way that will delete old build's console output,
but will not delete the old branch itself

is there any way to do that automatically without deleting the branch itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this buildDiscarder to your jenkinsfile

```
options {

  buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10', artifactNumToKeepStr: '5') 

}
```

`numToKeepStr`   <----- means number of build you want with console output.

`artifactNumToKeepStr`  <----- means number of artifacts you want to keep